# pfg axis discontinuity options

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

is there a way to set the length of the discontinuity in the x axis?
Here is the code I have used:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  thick,
    black,%Set the color of the main axes and numbers
    scale=0.389,
    axis lines=left,
    xmin=200,
    xmax=350,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3,
    major tick length=1.5pt,
    minor tick length=1pt,
    tick align = inside,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={anchor=north, draw=none},
    label style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The figure comes out like, with the discontinuity marker that occupies almost one unit.

[image]

I would like to have a shorter discontinuity marker, like the one in the picture below.

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal example such that others don't have to reinvent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *a possible* solution. Whether there is a better solution, I do not know. In

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@drawaxis@lines@preparediscont@for#1{%
        \ifnum\csname pgfplots@#1axisdiscontnum\endcsname>0
                \begingroup
                % this group employs several temporary dimension registers
                % and is therefor scoped:
                \let\disstart=\pgf@ya
                \let\disend=\pgf@yb
                \disend=\csname pgfplots@#1max@reg\endcsname
                \advance\disend by -\csname pgfplots@#1min@reg\endcsname
                \disend=\csname pgfplots@#1@veclength\endcsname\disend
                \ifcase\csname pgfplots@#1axisdiscontnum\endcsname\relax
                        % has already been checked above.
                \or
                        \def\discontstyle{decoration={zigzag,segment length=8pt, amplitude=3pt}}%
                        \advance \disend by -12pt
                \or
                        \def\discontstyle{decoration={ticks,segment length=4pt, amplitude=8pt}}%
                        \advance \disend by -8pt
                \fi
                \pgfplotscoordmath{#1}{datascaletrafo get params}%
                % if #1max + shift < 0pt  (shift is 0 without the scaling trafo)
                \ifdim\csname pgfplots@#1max@reg\endcsname<-\pgfplotsretvalb pt
                        % swap start and end
                        \disstart=\disend
                        \disend=4pt
                \else
                        \disstart=4pt
                \fi
                % carry local computations outside of group:
                \xdef\pgfplots@glob@TMPa{%
                        \noexpand\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname #1disstart\endcsname{\the\disstart}%
                        \noexpand\def\expandafter\noexpand\csname #1disend\endcsname{\the\disend}%
                        \noexpand\pgfkeysdef{/tikz/#1discont}{\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{\discontstyle}}%
                }%
                \endgroup
                \pgfplots@glob@TMPa
        \else
                \expandafter\def\csname #1disstart\endcsname{0pt}%
                \expandafter\def\csname #1disend\endcsname{0pt}%
                \pgfkeyslet{/tikz/#1discont}=\pgfutil@empty
        \fi
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  thick,
    black,%Set the color of the main axes and numbers
    scale=0.389,
    axis lines=left,
    xmin=200,
    xmax=350,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=3,
    major tick length=1.5pt,
    minor tick length=1pt,
    tick align = inside,
    axis x discontinuity=crunch,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={anchor=north, draw=none},
    label style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I changed

```
\def\discontstyle{decoration={zigzag,segment length=8pt, amplitude=3pt}}%
\advance \disend by -12pt
```

which was originally in `pgfplots.code.tex`

```
\def\discontstyle{decoration={zigzag,segment length=12pt, amplitude=4pt}}%
\advance \disend by -16pt
```

to get

[image]